# Evaluate text string as formula in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA to enter a formula in a column I have inserted into a downloaded data set. Apparently the data set I am inserting into is stored as text, so the inserted column inherits that characteristic. I want to be clear, it is not *formatted* as text, it has a *typename* of text.

I have `=2+2`, and the cell displays =2+2 instead of evaluating the formula and displaying 4. 
From some other suggestions, I tried

`activecell.value = Evaluate(activecell.value)`

That worked, and the cell would then display 4. But the formula is now gone, and the cell's formula = 4. I need the formula to stay for the purpose of using the autofill feature.

I could step through with a loop in VBA, but that seems over complicated. Is there a simple way to force excel to stop assuming the data type is text?

Comment: You can only have one value...  It can't be both a formula and a value.  Is your formula actually 2+2, or something else?

Comment: Make sure you are writing into the .formula property and not into the .value property. Also, make sure that the numberFormat isn't Text.

Comment: "not formatted as text, it has a typename of text" - can you explain the difference?  Cells on a worksheet don't have a "typename" property.  Likely you need to change the format to "General" before you insert the formula: that should fix it.

Comment: ...so it would help if you could include the relevant code for where you add the formula

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity. Though the question has been answered, I felt I should clarify. I did not realize this at the time, but what I meant by typename is apparently a native function 

'Typename(activecell.value)'

I was under the impression that this was somehow different from the number formatting within the cells because changing the number formats without re-evaluating did not change anything. I was simply missing a step, and therefore misunderstanding. I apologize!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both the Formula Bar and the cell show:

```
=2 + 2
```

Then this should fix the situation:

```
Sub qwerty()
    With ActiveCell
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Formula = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: @L42  Logical minds will converge to a logical solution.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! I had tried both of those steps, but not together. Thanks!